# Duplicate resources when using ProGuard and an Android application

Tags: android, resources, adt, proguard

I'm trying to use ProGuard with one of my applications, let's say A. This application includes another application as a library (let's say B). This is my proguard file.

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-injars      bin/classes
-libraryjars lib
```

When I first executed it, I got the following error:

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2012-01-05 12:18:55 - BSabadellHC-Entrega] Note: there were 1059 duplicate class     definitions.
[2012-01-05 12:18:55 - BSabadellHC-Entrega] java.io.IOException: Can't write     [/private/var/folders/19/321lw_654pzdqr8y34ysvsx80000gn/T/android_7971378611269030364.jar]     (Can't read     [/private/var/folders/19/321lw_654pzdqr8y34ysvsx80000gn/T/android_1457478862713006376.jar]     (Duplicate zip entry [com/ideaknowing/labs/android/ikarengine/e.class ==     android_1457478862713006376.jar:com/ideaknowing/labs/android/ikarengine/R$anim.class]))
```

The relevant parts for me are:

- There are duplicate objects
- They should because of the R files. It is said by the console that there are duplicate resources in R$anim (of course, since both the application A and the library B are including animations, layouts and so on).

So my idea was obviously to exclude from ProGuard the R files, and for that I included the following lines of code:

```
-keep public class net.firsrproject.android.R
-keep public class com.ideaknowing.labs.android.ikarengine.R
```

Nevertheless, I still get the same error (so I guess the files are still being included in Proguard). Has anybody experience with removing R files from ProGuard? Is there any tip or suggestion on how can I get rid of this error?

Thanks, and regards

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm receiving similar errors.

Comment: Even I'm receiving same error. Any luck yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `-injars bin/classes` if you are using android library project as the class files from the library are processed twice with this option (This worked for me in combination with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6492478/500865)).

If the above doesn't work try the `-dontnote` option.