# Duplicate files copied (Android Studio 0.4.0)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In my project I use httpcore and httpmime libraries from Apache. After update Android Studio to 0.4.0 I have this issue building my project:

```
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
File 1: /home/slava/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1/f7899276dddd01d8a42ecfe27e7031fcf9824422/httpmime-4.3.1.jar
File 2: /home/slava/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1/f7899276dddd01d8a42ecfe27e7031fcf9824422/httpmime-4.3.1.jar
```

Here is stacktrace of Gradle build:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':CMO:packageDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:286)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:93)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
        File 1: /home/slava/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1/f7899276dddd01d8a42ecfe27e7031fcf9824422/httpmime-4.3.1.jar
        File 2: /home/slava/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1/f7899276dddd01d8a42ecfe27e7031fcf9824422/httpmime-4.3.1.jar

        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.doFullTaskAction(PackageApplication.groovy:93)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:236)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:223)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:530)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:513)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
        File 1: /home/slava/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1/f7899276dddd01d8a42ecfe27e7031fcf9824422/httpmime-4.3.1.jar
        File 2: /home/slava/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1/f7899276dddd01d8a42ecfe27e7031fcf9824422/httpmime-4.3.1.jar

        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.Packager$JavaAndNativeResourceFilter.checkEntry(Packager.java:129)
        at com.android.builder.signing.SignedJarBuilder.writeZip(SignedJarBuilder.java:258)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.Packager.addResourcesFromJar(Packager.java:386)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.packageApk(AndroidBuilder.java:1175)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$packageApk.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.doFullTaskAction(PackageApplication.groovy:86)
        ... 62 more
```

The build.gradle looks like this:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':Inflector')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.1'
}
```

**Edit 1:**
Managed to solve this problem deleting files I had problem with from the local copy of httpmime library in META-INF directory

Comment: This seems to be bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61573. I don't know why it's only started being troublesome for you in this release.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but only by 26 minutes. Even if the question ends up being closed I hope the OP is forgiven for this.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

According to comment 14 in this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61573#c14 this is a bug in v0.7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin, and is due to be fixed soon in 0.7.1.

**EDIT**

Here are the notes from that bug about the addition for 0.7.1:

0.7.1 is out with the fix for this.

The DSL to exclude files is:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

You can add as many exclude statement as you want. The value is the archive path. No wildcard or glob support yet.

Comment: I also had to put 'META_INF/NOTICE.txt' for commons-lang3-3.1.jar usage.

Comment: Check the answer below from SK9 which exclude all necessary files.

Comment: @Scott Barta will it not cause open source violation?

Answer (score 284):

Follow the advice Gradle gives you at the end of the build. In my case it told me to add:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It does not comply Apache 2.0 license about NOTICE file, doesn't it? Or should I extract all of the NOTICE files and join them?

Comment: I have added all that. But still I have same issue. What else I can change?

Comment: I got this issue while I have added Azure Mobile service. Now it get resolved. Adding below line resolved the issue:
 
    packagingOptions { 
         exclude "META-INF/MSFTSIG.SF" 
         exclude "META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA" 
    }