# Duplicate files during packaging of APK, how to include several licenses in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm including 2 Apache licensed libraries into my Android app, when I attempt to generate the application I'm having the infamous "Duplicate files during packaging" error.

My first attempt to solve was, as suggested in a lot of places ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467127/error-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk)), to exclude the files, it worked and my apk was generated.

Then I realized that since 0.9.1. Gradle includes `pickFirst` option to place into the apk the first license found during compilation time.

```
 packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Problem is, Notice.txt contains only information about one of the licensed libraries, not both. For example, notice.txt of Apache Commons Codec is:

> Apache Commons Codec Copyright 2002-2011 The Apache Software
>   Foundation
>
> This product includes software developed by The Apache Software
>   Foundation (http://www.apache.org/).
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/test/org/apache/commons/codec/language/DoubleMetaphoneTest.java
>   contains  test data from
>   http://aspell.sourceforge.net/test/batch0.tab.
>
> Copyright (C) 2002 Kevin Atkinson (kevina@gnu.org). Verbatim copying
>    and distribution of this entire article is permitted in any medium, provided this notice is preserved.
>
> ---

and Joda Time's:

> =============================================================================
>   = NOTICE file corresponding to section 4d of the Apache License Version 2.0 =
>   ============================================================================= This product includes software developed by Joda.org
>   (http://www.joda.org/).

My question is, is there a way to "merge" the `license` and `notice` files automatically? I assume this is a common problem so I guess I'm not the first one facing it.

Comment: Gradle has no means of taking two random text files, realize that they have commonalities (by some means) and then assemble them into a single file (by some means) that is legally valid. There may be a Gradle/Groovy way to concatenate them; you would need to discuss with your legal counsel whether that is a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off writing your own LICENSE.txt file - you still need to provide one that covers your app, right?

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. Yes, @Jolta my temporal solution is to write my own license and notice files, but I thought that maybe there was a way to automatize this and don't need to manually modify my files if a new library is added. I know it's not a big deal, but considering the number of apps that include > 1 library (probably with licenses) I was thinking that maybe there was an automatic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new "merge" packagingOption that looks like it will avoid this error while still allowing you to include important things like open source licenses.

*(I am not a lawyer and not a gradle expert so make sure you understand how to honor your own licenses)*

It combines duplicates into one file.

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions

Example:

```
 packagingOptions {
    merge 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    merge 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    merge 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    merge 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    merge 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```