# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/jersey-module-version

Tags: android, gradle, duplicates

- Android Studio: 2.2.2
- Gradle: 2.2.2

I have this common problem but the usual solutions don't seem to be helping.  I've even broken it down to just this one library on a new solution.  To replicate, fire up a new Android project and simply drop this one line into your dependencies.

```
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.13'
```

Here is the error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/jersey-module-version
>     File1: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.13/ec38c57a78940bf5f8f5971307ca89406849647/jersey-client-1.13.jar
>     File2: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/1.13/4326a56dc6b2d67b7313905c353e1af225bb164f/jersey-core-1.13.jar

I have tried

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675325/316614
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698598/316614
- [Error :: duplicate files during packaging of APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467127/error-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk)

I can't figure out what to exclude.  Has anybody see this?  Easy to replicate, try it out.

Comment: You tried excluding, `META-INF/jersey-module-version`? Because none of those answers say that

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like just another example of a problem with these builds.  I was able to block it by just looking at the error.  So the error told me the duplicate was jersey-module-version.  I went into my libraries and browsed the folders to the META-INF and found that file there, no extension.

So it was a matter of excluding it.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/jersey-module-version'
}
```

What is strange is that this is supposed to be fixed.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158630#makechanges