# how to resolve duplicate entry in bulid gradle in android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to import eclipse project into android studio.After that adding my jar file i.e support jar  into `build gradle` file whatever I have used in eclipse. While doing that getting below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/database/DatabaseUtilsCompat.class
```

and my build gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
configurations {
   // all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
   // all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }

}

dependencies {
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/glide-3.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/library-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
   compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4' // exclude duplicate library
    }

}
```

Comment: I was stuck here. Please help me

Answer (score 4):

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/v4/database/DatabaseUtilsCompat.class

Problem

- **`exclude module: 'support-v4'`**

**Don't**

```
compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4' // exclude duplicate library
}
```

**You Should Use**

```
compile group: 'org.eclipse.paho', name: 'org.eclipse.paho.android.service', version: '1.0.2'
```

If problem coming then add this in your `build.gradle` section

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** .

Comment: @Durga add `packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }`

Comment: @Durga within `android { ...}`

Comment: @Durga https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467127/error-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk . Hope this helps you .

Comment: @Durga Let me inform please .

Comment: I'm trying to resolve with ur link.. bt it's giving same.. any other mistake i did in my code???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156356/discussion-between-durga-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: @Durga Add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:` version instead of `+` . Like `10.2.6` . https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: @Durga Solved this yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Put below code below `buildTypes` and **rebuild** again project

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Comment: In build.gradle ...below buildTypes  tag

Answer (score 0):

Remove  the line

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4' // exclude duplicate library
}
```

and add this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2
```

Also add this inside the android{  }

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

For more information check this link 
https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/

Comment: I tried this.. not working.. give me any other solution

Comment: if i replace this giving another error .. install repository and sync project