# Android Studio : Duplicate files error with Gradle

Tags: gradle, android-studio, robospice

I have an error when I want to add Robospice library; this is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
  // Check on it to know witch Android API level is necessary:
  // http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
    compile "com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.11"
}
```

But unfortunately, Gradle gives me this error:

> duplicate files during packaging of APK D:\blablabla\build\apk\mtc-debug-unaligned.apk
>   Execution failed for task ':mtc:packageDebug'.
>   Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
>       File 1: C:\Users\Anthony.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.2.1\66f13681add50ca9e4546ffabafaaac7645db3cf\commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
>       File 2: C:\Users\Anthony.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.2.1\66f13681add50ca9e4546ffabafaaac7645db3cf\commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar

Thanks for your help !

Anthony

Comment: I solved my problem; I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20698598/3409503 !

Answer (score 0):

uses this code to solve your problem:

`android{
         packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        }
     }`

but if the problem remains, you must look for the file you need ignorie during generation of apk.and add to packagingOptions like in the code above