# Maven Repository for Apache Http MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to import `'MultipartEntityBuilder'`  file to an Android project but cannot for the life of me find the right repository.

Have tried this three off Apache HttpComponents website with no luck :

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:4.1'
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

answering my own question (after about an hour of searching)...

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
```

the last one has `MultipartEntityBuilder` in it. Can take out `httpasyncclient` and `httpclient`

Also need to adds excludes in you gradle file: [Duplicate files copied (Android Studio 0.4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673888/duplicate-files-copied-android-studio-0-4-0)

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Spits the dummy otherwise and tells you stuff (in red) you don't care about related to duplicate files.