# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I use android studio 2.0 version. I use the gradle to build the program, take this the question:
[image]

I know this question in the Android studio 0.7version have the same question. I see the Link [Duplicate files copied (Android Studio 0.4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673888/duplicate-files-copied-android-studio-0-4-0)

But, I follow this way:
[image]

But this method it doesn't work for me!

Could you help me?  I am waiting for you!

Comment: update your gradle file

Comment: @Ashvi  thank you , But not this question. I  know this quesetion is the andorid studio 2.0 question. So i download the android studio 1.4 version, run the progrom ,It is OK !  Just because the Android studio 2.0 inner quesetion!

Comment: I am having the same problem but it is happening with every maven file.  Right now I have exclude statements for a dozen files.  That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I came across the same issue and found the duplicate file is nothing to do with AndroidStudio 2.0 preview, maybe it's cause by gradle.
please try following:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.belerweb/pinyin4j/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.belerweb/pinyin4j/pom.properties'
}
```

if you have resovled the duplicate issue but come across the ClassNotFoundIssue please refre to this [topic](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194990&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Comment: @LalitPoptani which version of AS are you using?

Comment: @Weibo Android Studio 2.1 Preview 5

Answer (score 1):

Add below text on build.gradle file solve problem

```
packagingOptions {
   exclude  'META-INF/maven/com.belerweb/pinyin4j/pom.properties'
}
```

If getting more error DuplicateFileException add file with exclude. 
Like :

Error

```
 Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.belerweb/pinyin4j/pom.properties
```

Solution

```
 exclude  'META-INF/maven/com.belerweb/pinyin4j/pom.properties'
```