# NoSuchMethodError error when using Proguard for OnClickListener

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

When using proguard to build my android application I get the following error as soon as the first activity is shown to the user the application then completely crashes out:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.XmlResourceParser.i
       at ActivityNewUserSetup.OnClickOKButton()
       at ActivityNewUserSetup.onCreate()
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

The code it appears to be referring to is in the ActivityNewUserSetup class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...code omitted for clarity
    Button btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Confirm_Selection);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(OnClickOKButton());
}

View.OnClickListener OnClickOKButton()
{
    return new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ...code omitted for clarity
        }
     }
}
```

I've used the basic proguard template configuration file found here:

[Android: What are the recommended configurations for Proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068251/android-what-are-the-recommended-configurations-for-proguard)

If it is the listener that is tripping the function what do I need to add in the proguard file to stop this?

My version of proguard is 4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the lib jar for android sdk ...

```
-libraryjars  /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-19/android.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

OR

For the open source apis like your parser, you can specify 'keep' for those packages as sample below from project that uses lots of OSS.

```
-keep        class ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.** { *; }
-keep public class com.mobeta.android.** { *; }
-keep        class com.slidingmenu.lib.** { *; }
-keep        class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keep        class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.callbacks** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.dialog.video** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.exceptions** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.player** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.notification** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.remotecontrol** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.utils** { *; }
-keep        class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.widgets** { *; }
-keep        class android.support.v13.** { *; }
-keep        class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep        class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep        class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep        class com.androidquery.** { *; }
```

you could also read the proguard tips on api's.

Comment: Thanks for clue robert it was a 3rd party JAR throwing things off

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer, the error message is a red herring.  Robert Rowntree answer clued me in to what might be happening the 3rd party packages.

In this activity I use the ksoap2-android-assembly-3.2.0.jar, by adding the following to the proguard-project.txt

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class org.kobjects.** { *; }
-keep class org.ksoap2.** { *; }
-keep class org.kxml2.** { *; }
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

It now works, so the lesson here is look to your 3rd party Jar files and try and put a load of KEEP statements in proguard-project.txt to rule out this possibility. While not strictly the answer to the question Robert Rowntree provided the clues to do this, so he will get the correct answer. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in and it works for me. I am posting what worked for me the only change was I added a semicolon on the onclick listener which I didnot see in your code. Heres the code:

```
public class Sample extends Activity {
Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(OnClickOKButton());
}

View.OnClickListener OnClickOKButton() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Sample.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    };//added semicolon here
}
}
```

My guess is that the function is available on compile time but not on runtime(preety unlikely though).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've got the issue the error is alittle bit of a red herring.