# How to obfuscate whole app (methods and classes) with proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

please help me.

I try to understand, but all the examples are very different.

The standard configurations does not found.

Do I need something extra to static methods?

Why do I have to describe the extra classes are serialized?

I have 1 Activity, several Fragments, Adapters, few classes with static functions.

This is described in sufficient?

I have a lot of interfaces and AsyncTasks - for them need something extra to describe?

For example took from this example.
[Android: What are the recommended configurations for Proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068251/android-what-are-the-recommended-configurations-for-proguard)

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass1 {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass2 {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass3 {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass4 {
    public static <methods>;
}

#To keep parcelable classes (to serialize - deserialize objects to sent through Intents)
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

#Keep the R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Thanks!