# Null pointer exception when using ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

I am getting `NullPointerException` at a line in my code. But when not using ProGuard, everything works just fine.

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
                                                                     at com.random.testing.Details$3.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at c.g$a$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here's my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn okio.**

-dontnote retrofit2.Platform

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: post your proguard file, chum!

Comment: (that is the proguard config file, to make that clear)

Comment: post the proguard file

Comment: Added `proguard-rules.pro`

Comment: @SaikCaskey What do you I am missing in my proguard file?

Comment: I don't think you're keeping the files you want - look for standard proguard file definitions ([this is a useful one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6492478/5346097))

Comment: could you post the call to toArray as well? 
That should help speculate some more specific causes. 
Proguard literally strips code out of your apk. Read some of the stuff in that answer/question I linked you to for more info.

Comment: @SaikCaskey This is the statement where the error occurs: `movies.addAll(response.body().getMovies());`

Comment: `response.body().getMovies()` returns null. Are you using Jackson to parse the JSON?

Comment: hmm I can quickly see me asking you to post a lot of code here.. Try the proguard file in the answer I linked you to. If you cannot get any luck with using different proguard rules, come back here and edit your question to include all of the involved code- i.e, all of the xml, java and gradle that is involved in getting that response and putting it into your array! One way to do proguard is just to start with nothing excluded, then slowly narrow it down until all of your app is included and only the required parts of libs

Comment: Sure. I'll go through that linked file and try to resolve it. Thanks.