# How exclude a package from an imported android library?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I have two projects:

- 1- Project "A": Which is the Android app project.
- 2- Project "B": A huge Android library project that I use in almost all my projects.

I need to import 2 classes by reference from "B" and use them in "A". I don't need the rest of of packages and subclasses of "B" to be built and packaged inside "A"'s apk file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html), you will find it's quite good at stripping unused classes and methods out of the final binary.

Comment: that sounds promising, do u know any tutorial that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you export the classes from project B into a jar file and import that jar in project A?

Comment: I thought of doing that, but some of these classes rely on the autogenerated R file of Project B

Comment: Oh.. in that case you should try using Proguard as @Graham suggested. It's very easy to configure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android