# How to shrink the size of APK file?

Tags: android, apk

i want to shrink the size of my apk file because in my application lots of images there.
and because of the image my apk file size is too large..

Comment: I thonk take images small size .png format then its size reduce.

Comment: Apply Lossy Compression for your images.

Comment: Also see http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/

Answer (score 2):

An APK file is basically a ZIP file. There's no way of reducing its size any further. Instead, you should check whether you can

1. reduce image sizes (either the dimensions or better compression) or
2. replace some of the images by custom drawing code, creating them at runtime

If neither 1. or 2. are possible, I guess you just have to accept the APK size as it is.

Answer (score 2):

In images you have no way to reduce the size without reducing the size of the images themselves but you can do one of 2 things:

1. Not having them on the APK and downloading them on first run (use internal or external storage)
2. Use shapes to replace images (where they can be replaced)

The code you can reduce by using proguard: [Enabling ProGuard in Eclipse for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android/5040675#5040675)

Answer (score 0):

If you have many images you can exclude them from the *.apk, download them at first run and save on sdcard

Comment: Of course you save resources on sdcard only if you have sdcard. But if you haven't this you can use [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Answer (score 0):

**Apk is already in  compressed form** but  by following given points you may **reduce it to some extent**.

1. Try enabling [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), even without obfuscation and reduce your byte code. It will remove unused Java code from your dependencies
2. Check for unneeded jars , resources like images or videos.
3. Convert large images to smaller one by changing resolution . and
   convert `Jpeg images` to `PNG`. But it is even better to put your image on Web and retrieve them using AsyncTask.
4. Remove unnecessary `java.classes` and `xml` from the project.
5. Don't add large songs or audio to raw or assest.