# Android protect app with proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I've created my app and following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android) I've done this:

In proguard-project.txt:

```
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-optimizationpasses 10
-dontwarn android.support.**
-verbose


-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class ClassOne extends Activity
-keep public class ClassTwo extends ListActivity
-keep public class ClassThree extends ListActivity
-keep public class ClassFour extends ListActivity
-keep public class ClassFive extends ListActivity
-keep public class ClassSix extends ListActivity
-keep public class ClassSeven extends Activity
```

Those are the class on my `manifest`

In project.properties uncomment the line:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

I've exported my app and opened used dex2jar and jd-gui to see if add any success.

The problem is that the code is almost as I've coded and is very easy to understand.

Am I doing something wrong? Can I improve the obfuscation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have copied the 'keeps' literally as in

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

rather than substituting your own actual activity names

Comment: Thanks. Done that but the result is the same :(

Comment: I still have my Proguard configuration in the proguard.cfg file and to turn Proguard on, I have the line proguard.config=proguard.cfg
in project.properties. (I don't know whether these are the currently recommended names though! Plus I only do release builds using Ant, just using Eclipse for the debug builds) Sorry it didn't work for your configuration

Comment: Ok. Changed `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt` to `proguard.config=proguard-project.txt`. Its seams to be better, nevertheless its relatively easy to understand the code. Thanks NickT

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

I've removed the lines:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

And now its as I expected

Since all examples on the internet have those lines I tough they were important.

Testing my app and it is working as expected