# Cannot add ActionBarSherlock lib

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an apps including my owngame, facebookSDK.
It was built normally. 
But after I added ActionBarSherlock, although I haven't using any function of ABS an error appears :

```
Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

The strange thing is it worked on the last day. But today I open Eclipse and start working, this shit come. 
I really get stuck here, bcz I have to use ABS to add different kinds of action bar that ABS support.

Some people said that I have to multiply the dex file . But I think It's not mainstream and not programmatic. I prefer to use another way.

Can you help me solve this ?

Comment: Try to clean the projects.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried for more billion times. I spent lots of time trying fixing it myself. But I wasted hours and I need some reality solution in this case.

Comment: Check the versions of support library in ABS and in your project. If they are different revision, this won't let you build your app either.

Comment: I have checked and changed the android_support_v4 many times. I only use only jar file in one project and others projects point to it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app has grown to the point that there are more than 2**16 methods. Check out this for more details. [How to solve the issue with Dalvik compiler limitation on 64K methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436956/how-to-solve-the-issue-with-dalvik-compiler-limitation-on-64k-methods)