# The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K, multidexenabled is not working and failed for task ':app:clean'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Can anyone help me how to solve this! It was working yesterday, but today when I run my app again this morning, it is not working.

This is my **build.gladle**...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brandtechnosolutions.petbaazar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile `enter code here`'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have tried to use this...

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and this...

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

but then a new error comes...

**Could not find method logIn(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class**

This is logIn() method in my **MainActivity**...

```
void logIn(View view) {                        //called when log in button pressed
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);                 // start web activity
}
```

Also **Instant Run** is not working in android studio... shows error:

**Execution failed for task ':app:clean'. Unable to delete file**

when I enable the instant run. Please help!

Comment: Do you need whole  `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`? You can include only the parts of play-services you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 64k method limit error on 56k methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357228/android-64k-method-limit-error-on-56k-methods)

Comment: @Kevinrob you truly didn't even read till the end, did you? It is not related to multiDex, as you can see from the newest error. He fixed the multiDex issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your onClick method isn't `public`. I think the error is not related to multiDex anymore. Change the signature to:

```
public void logIn(View view)...
```

Comment: What is going on with people at SO? This is the answer to the question for sure, and I am getting a minus? Why ? What am I even trying for then?

Comment: It was working with non-public onClick method yesterday, but today it is not working!

Comment: @SayanMukherjee Try changing to this and let me know if it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
android{
...
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem you did. If the app contains too many method calls, you must make it a Multidex Application. However, I don't think you really need to do that.

In your app.gradle you have the line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'` which basically takes the WHOLE play services module, which is huge. I guess your app takes forever to build as well.

So, delete the general play services dependency (but keep `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'` if you need it) and add perhaps you need to add the following line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` AFTER the end of your dependency list.

Then you can remove all the multidex crap :)

Comment: Done what you have just mention, but error coming: Error:(40, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, this is what I have done...

add it to build.gradle

```
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "1g"
    }
```

and...

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and changing onClick method to public...

```
void logIn(View view) {                        //called when log in button pressed
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);                 // start web activity
}
```

I don't know actually which of these actually work, I think together!

Thank you guys for your time and help, thanks a lot!