# What is 64K method counts limit for an Android application and their graph of connection

Tags: android, dex

I have seen this error in Android app and have seen many posts on stackoverflow like [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357228/android-64k-method-limit-error-on-56k-methods) but have not got exactly the meaning of 64K method counts limit of an Android application

What exactly this limit means , is it the User defined methods or overall imported methods too from classes

If yes ... how can I see the graph of reference of methods connected .

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: does it mean thats the limit for number of user specified methods and multidex

Comment: It means all methods inside dex file, include different libraries. Prior to Android 5 APK can contains only one dex file, after that few ones(multidex)

Comment: It is the limit of total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit also counts all the method that you add with your build.gradle, and your custom classes too. By default all your classes are compiled to a single classes.dex file. That file can only contain up to 64K (i.e. 64 * 1024 = 65536) methods. When you add a multi Dex support in your build.gradle, you allow it to compile the classes into multiple Dex files and be referred from their respective Dex files.

You can get the reference and methods of your apk file in Android studio and check which methods are taking how much space.

Comment: How can I get this count of the reference and methods inside Android Studio?

Comment: @EdwardKoetsjarjan You can find details on how to use the APK analyzer on Android Studio at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer

Comment: another tool that is shipped with the Android SDK that you can use is `dexdump`