# Paypal Integration gives me error in android

Tags: android, paypal, android-studio

After adding PayPalAndroidSDK-2.8.6.jar file to my lib folder
I am getting error 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\marwha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output E:\android\RocketResumeBuilder\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=E:\android\RocketResumeBuilder\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

I am using android studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve the issue with Dalvik compiler limitation on 64K methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436956/how-to-solve-the-issue-with-dalvik-compiler-limitation-on-64k-methods)

Comment: This is a common problem.  Search for "DexIndexOverflowException" (or simply visit https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).