# Error Building Android App

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, cyanogenmod

I am getting a weird error when I am trying to build a app. I don't think it's related to my code and need some help in resolving it. When I press run, the logcat giving me this error:

Could not upload stats checkin to cyanogen server

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
>          at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:318)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:201)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:155)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
>                                                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>                                                                                              at com.android.settings.cmstats.StatsUploadJobService.uploadToCyanogen(StatsUploadJobService.java:223)
>                                                                                              at com.android.settings.cmstats.StatsUploadJobService.access$000(StatsUploadJobService.java:43)
>                                                                                              at com.android.settings.cmstats.StatsUploadJobService$StatsUploadTask.doInBackground(StatsUploadJobService.java:121)
>                                                                                              at com.android.settings.cmstats.StatsUploadJobService$StatsUploadTask.doInBackground(StatsUploadJobService.java:93)
>                                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

The gradle console then says:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>           com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>               at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:484)
>               at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:261)
>               at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:473)
>               at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:161)
>               at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
>               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>               at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

I am wondering if it to do with my phone's hardware or the cyanogenmod software running on it which causes the error.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I suggest that you search around for `DexIndexOverflowException`.

Comment: Can you post your app level build.gradle file?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l)

Answer (score 1):

You hit the DEX 64k method limit.

There are few solutions which will help you to resolve this problem:

- remove unused gradle dependencies
- replace libaries with huge amount of methods with smaller ones, e.g.:

  ```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
  ```

  ->

  ```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
  ...
  ```
- remove unused code by configuring the [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)
- enable [Multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle):

  build.gradle

  ```
  android {
      ...

      defaultConfig {
          ...
          // Enabling multidex support.
          multiDexEnabled true
      }
      ...
  }

  dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  }
  ```

  AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
      <application
          ...
          android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
          ...
      </application>
  </manifest>
  ```

Reference:

[Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Answer (score 0):

This line `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536` states that you are over the 64k method limit the Compiler has for every .dex file. Read up on it. Solutions include using `Multidex` or more solutions here https://www.contentful.com/blog/2014/10/30/android-and-the-dex-64k-methods-limit/. This maybe a duplicate of other issues. Look at
[How to solve the issue with Dalvik compiler limitation on 64K methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436956/how-to-solve-the-issue-with-dalvik-compiler-limitation-on-64k-methods)