# Proguard: Blank screen after exiting webview or browser

Tags: android, proguard

I enabled proguard using following info I tried both popular answers
[Enabling ProGuard in Eclipse for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android).

When I hit back button from WebviewActivity or the Browser (started by intent in my application), app shows blank screen, However If disable the proguard the behaviour is normal.

NOTE: This only happens when I hit back button, webview or content is shown properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
class:

```
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
  public *;
}
```

from Auto generated `proguard-project.txt` file.

Comment: thanks what do you mean by  specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface class. I use webview one as in activity WebView which is android.webkit.WebView and other one is startAcivity for opening an URL.

Comment: did you added above lines in your `proguard.txt` file ?