# How To Protect Source Code While Android Development

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I decompiled an android apk with dex2jar just now. The package name and **class name has been shorten like the screenshot**.

[image: Screenshot]

I want to konw how to do that.

PS: I use **Android Studio** IDE.

Comment: After reverse-engineering a dozen apps I would say that obfuscation makes it harder to examine the source code. But not hard enough to stop you from doing it.

Comment: Check out this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android

It helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only point in code obfuscation at development time is to check that the obfuscation doesn't break anything. Beside this, the component that manage the obfuscation is the ProGuard:

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by
>   removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with
>   semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file
>   that is more difficult to reverse engineer. Because ProGuard makes
>   your application harder to reverse engineer, it is important that you
>   use it when your application utilizes features that are sensitive to
>   security like when you are Licensing Your Applications.

To enable it in android studio:

> Note: When using Android Studio, you must add Proguard to your
>   gradle.build file's build types. For more information, see the Gradle
>   Plugin User Guide.

To know more about the ProGuard tool [just read the android's documentation :)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)