# Hide URL Link in HTTP POST in android

Tags: android

I would like to hide my URL in HTTP POST Request from USERS. Like if I extract my APK I would be able to see the link when I use the following to access few details from mySQL in the code.

```
private static String url_all_contacts = "http://www.mydomain.com/xxxsa/all.php;
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_contacts, "GET", params);
```

I would like to know is there any way to hide the URL?

Thanks!

Comment: use Volley Lib For Making HTTP Request

Comment: Obfuscate your code. try progaurd http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but why are you doing this? Your variable `url_all_contacts` hints to .. well.. sending all contacts. And then you don't want anyone to see what url you are using. Are you doing something you shouldn't?

Comment: @AndoMasahashi : Why Volley lib when I can do the same using json..?

Comment: @Pr38y: I already tried progaurd but I am still able to see the links clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Proguard` to hide your code. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android) question for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi : I am already using proguard when I extract the apk I can easily see the link..

Comment: Something wrong with your progaurd-config. Are you enabling it? because Progaurd surely obfuscate the code. I am using it in almost all my project.

Comment: It is doing the job but not the link?