# Noclassdeffound error com.paypal.sdk.paymentactivity in android

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate PayPal using `paypalsdk.jar` in my android project.

When I am running project, noclassdeffounderror is coming with this package noclassdeffounderror:com.paypal.sdk.paymentactivity.In my log end of line noclassfoundexcetion also coming I import my paypalsdk2.9.3.jar in right `click my project --> properties --> java build path ---> add external` `library --> browse jar location --> add paypalsdk2.9.3.jar` and I checked in import and export tab.

In this case also its not running and my app crashing. sometimes am getting Unable to execute dex: **Cannot merge new index 65992 into a non-jumbo instruction!** and **Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 65992 into a non-jumbo instruction!**

How to clear this issue and how I can make payment using PayPal.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to how many methods you can have in your Android application. There are two ways you can get around this:

1. Increase your method limit: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
2. Use proguard to eliminate unused methods: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Another note: If you are running proguard, you may be getting that noclassdeffounderror because proguard thinks you aren't using that method and has removed it from the compiled libraries.

Comment: thanks for reply dear friend. Am using eclipse adt for my development so that how i can fix this issue..

Comment: I'm going to advise you to switch to Android Studio because Eclipse ADT has been deprecated.

Comment: thanks for your advice friend but already i started my project with adt eclipse once i complete this project i can switch over to android studio so will please help me to come out of this issue

Comment: Proguard can be used in Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android