# Android - Need a way to create the library(.aar file) without source code

Tags: android, android-library, aar, source-code-protection

My aim is to be able to distribute the android library application only as binary(WITHOUT SOURCE) to other developers. 
So that they can make their own apps with it.

I am developing two android applications. The first one is library application should act as a kind of SDK. 
The second one application should use the library application and make the original app.

I am using android studio to develop the applications. I have completed the implementations of the library application and generated the .aar.

Now I am using my own SDK(.aar) to build the second application. I can use the .aar in my second application.

The problem is that, android studio can decompile my SDK(.aar). But I don't want to share the source code.

**Note:** My librarySDK doesn't contain any UI elements such as Activity, Resources.

Is there any way to create the SDK(.aar) without source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yup for that you need to use **proguard** when you build **SDK/Library aar** file

Change `minifyEnabled` to `true` in your SDK/Library gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true //enable proguard
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

[Enabling ProGuard in Eclipse for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added this and I got the below exception during compilation. Error:Execution failed for task ':libraryapp'.
> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?

Comment: yes you will get alot of error because of obfuscation and yes you need to specify '-keep' or '-dontwarn'

Comment: check this out https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-steps-to-enable-ProGuard-in-Android-Studio