# proguard returned with error code 1 android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-proguard

while exporting signed application package in android application from eclipse, i am getting the error `proguard returned with error code 1 :see console`

here is my **project.property** file

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.2=../ratinglibrary
android.library.reference.3=../appcompat_v7
android.library.reference.4=../ViewpagerLibrary
```

please anyone suggest me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You better follow ProGuards advice and see what's in the console.

Comment: Hi pb123, have you add proguard rules in your proguard-project text file? You can check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732656/enabling-proguard-in-eclipse-for-android

Comment: @UrMi what are the rules and how could i add that, can u please explain me?